# How to work with isotope filter and bootstrap accordion?

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am trying to use isotope js filter where each filterable items have a bootstrap 3.3.7 accordion inside. This works fine but when clicking on any accordion item, then there is a sliding bug appears. Here is an example of the bug https://codepen.io/paulhaem/pen/ZJELJr

As you can see, once you click on any item, it slides down first but the next item is sliding down a little bit later. Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
        // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.portfolio-grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
        layoutMode: 'vertical', 
        hiddenStyle: {
            opacity: 0
        },
        visibleStyle: {
            opacity: 1
        },

    });

    $grid.on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
        $(this).slideDown(
            function() {
                $grid.isotope('layout');    
            }

        );
    });


    // filter items on button click
    $('.button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });

    // change is-checked class on buttons
    $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
      var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
      $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
      });
    });
```